# LESS: Unrecognized input error when using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, harp

After upgrading Harp, I started getting an *Unrecognized Input* error in an irrelevant line of CSS.

> Less -> CSS (Unrecognised input) /Users/jorge/Dropbox/harp.io/apps/mysite.com/public/css/main.less

Using Bootstrap v2.2.2 and Harp v0.9.4.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After digging for a while, I found that the error was coming from the `mixin.less` file where the `#grid` stuff was getting defined.

This is what the file had originally:

```
(~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
```

After reading the [LESS change log](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-beta-1--2), I found that they changed the syntax so you can now use variables directly without needing the ~ hack. So I changed my `mixin.less` to look like this:

```
.span@{index} { .span(@index); }
```

There are a couple of other lines that you need to change, but they all follow the same format.

`(~".offset@{index}") { .offset(@index); }` changes to → `.offset@{index} { .offset(@index); }`

Comment: I'm a little late to the game working on a legacy project. Did you only change the one line, or did you change the entire `.spanX` all the way past `@index-1`?

Comment: I remember changing it in a bunch of places. Look for that pattern `(~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }` and replace it with the suggestion.