# Unrecognised input on CSS creation

Tags: php, symfony, less

I'm trying to make the assetic:dump in my Symfony2 application. But I'm getting the error below.

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input in /home/vozi/webapp/vendor/duo/cms-bundle/Duo/CMSBundle/Resources/public/vendor/bootstrap/2.0.2/src/less/mixins.less on line 519, column 3:
518
519   .core (@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {
520

ParseError: Unrecognised input in /home/vozi/webapp/vendor/duo/cms-bundle/Duo/CMSBundle/Resources/public/vendor/bootstrap/2.0.2/src/less/mixins.less on line 519, column 3:
518
519   .core (@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {
520
```

The error is returned when the lines below are processed.

```
// The Grid
#grid {

  .core (@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {

    .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}

    .offsetX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~".offset@{index}") { .offset(@index); }
      .offsetX(@index - 1);
    }
    .offsetX (0) {}

    .offset (@columns) {
      margin-left: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1)) + (@gridGutterWidth * 2);
    }

    .span (@columns) {
      width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1));
    }

    .row {
      margin-left: @gridGutterWidth * -1;
      .clearfix();
    }

    [class*="span"] {
      float: left;
      margin-left: @gridGutterWidth;
    }

    // Set the container width, and override it for fixed navbars in media queries
    .container,
    .navbar-fixed-top .container,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .container { .span(@gridColumns); }

    // generate .spanX and .offsetX
    .spanX (@gridColumns);
    .offsetX (@gridColumns);

  }

  .fluid (@fluidGridColumnWidth, @fluidGridGutterWidth) {

    .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~"> .span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}

    .span (@columns) {
      width: (@fluidGridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@fluidGridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1));
    }

    .row-fluid {
      width: 100%;
      .clearfix();
      > [class*="span"] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: @fluidGridGutterWidth;
      }
      > [class*="span"]:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
      }

      // generate .spanX
      .spanX (@gridColumns);
    }

  }

  .input(@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {

    .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~"input.span@{index}, textarea.span@{index}, .uneditable-input.span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}

    .span(@columns) {
      width: ((@gridColumnWidth) * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1)) - 10;
    }

    input,
    textarea,
    .uneditable-input {
      margin-left: 0; // override margin-left from core grid system
    }

    // generate .spanX
    .spanX (@gridColumns);

  }

}
```

Anyone knows the root cause of my problem. I'm newer in Symfony and Less.

Comment: What less parser are you using?

Comment: node.js: lessc 1.7.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error. But I don't know where.

Comment: older less compilers had issues with `(~".offset@{index}")` where the ~ was inside

Comment: Well if you are using the 1.7.0 version then that is not your issue. what are `@gridColumnWidth` and `@gridGutterWidth` defined as?

Comment: I don't find the definition. I don't know the less syntax. But when I comment this line `(~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }` the problem is solve, not all, but this error is solve.

Comment: what are is config for assetic? can you add it to the question?

Comment: Bootstrap 2.0.x is incompatible with recent Less versions (since v1.3.3). `(~"@{var}")` syntax is deprecated in favor of `@{var}`. Upgrade to Bootstrap 3 or manually fix the grid mixins by replacing `(~".span@{index}")` with `.span@{index}` etc..

Comment: @seven-phases-max, please could your add your comment as an answer so this question can be accepted?

Comment: @Bass Jobsen, I guess I'll better vote to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19553367 to not increase entropy.

Comment: @seven-phases-max, yes that's a better option! thanks