# why is this less code not compiling?

Tags: css, less

I've extracted this piece of less code that is causing a web app to throw an error when it runs an asynchronous task to compile this less code. I've never written less before and from my initial perusal of the docs I can't seem to find whats wrong. Anybody know what's wrong? 
This is the error:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input in /Users/****/Desktop/testmoreless.css on line 4, column 3:
3
4   .core (@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {
5
```

This is the entire piece of code:

```
#grid {

  .core (@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {

    .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}

    .offsetX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~".offset@{index}") { .offset(@index); }
      .offsetX(@index - 1);
    }
    .offsetX (0) {}

    .offset (@columns) {
      margin-left: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1)) + (@gridGutterWidth * 2);
    }

    .span (@columns) {
      width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1));
    }

    .row {
      margin-left: @gridGutterWidth * -1;
      .clearfix();
    }

    [class*="span"] {
      float: left;
      margin-left: @gridGutterWidth;
    }

    // Set the container width, and override it for fixed navbars in media queries
    .container,
    .navbar-fixed-top .container,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .container { .span(@gridColumns); }

    // generate .spanX and .offsetX
    .spanX (@gridColumns);
    .offsetX (@gridColumns);

  }

  .fluid (@fluidGridColumnWidth, @fluidGridGutterWidth) {

    .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~"> .span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}

    .span (@columns) {
      width: (@fluidGridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@fluidGridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1));
    }

    .row-fluid {
      width: 100%;
      .clearfix();
      > [class*="span"] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: @fluidGridGutterWidth;
      }
      > [class*="span"]:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
      }

      // generate .spanX
      .spanX (@gridColumns);
    }

  }

  .input(@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth) {

    .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~"input.span@{index}, textarea.span@{index}, .uneditable-input.span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}

    .span(@columns) {
      width: ((@gridColumnWidth) * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1)) - 10;
    }

    input,
    textarea,
    .uneditable-input {
      margin-left: 0; // override margin-left from core grid system
    }

    // generate .spanX
    .spanX (@gridColumns);

  }

}
```

Comment: could you also include your variable data please (ie. @gridColumnWidth: XXXX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19553368/244353).

Quoting the answer verbatim:

---

This is what the file had originally:

```
(~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
```

After reading the [LESS change log](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-beta-1--2), I found that they changed the syntax so you can now use variables directly without needing the ~ hack. So I changed my `mixin.less` to look like this:

```
.span@{index} { .span(@index); }
```

There are a couple of other lines that you need to change, but they all follow the same format.

`(~".offset@{index}") { .offset(@index); }` changes to → `.offset@{index} { .offset(@index); }`