# Weird less issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to improve a build script that uses less to build some CSS and I am getting this. I didn't write this less, but my google-fu has been unable to figure out what is going on here and how to fix it

```
ParseError: Missing closing ')' in /Users/zkessin/Documents/Voalte/voalte-one/webvadmin/src/less/bootstrap/mixins.less on line 536, column 9:
535     .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
536       (~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
537       .spanX(@index - 1);
```

My only guess is that this was written with an old version of less and I am using the current version

Comment: I guess we need to see a bit more of your mixins.less code. Depending on the compiler version that you are using, you probably don't even need `(~".span@{index}")`. Even `.span@{index}` would work fine in the latest versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS: Unrecognized input error when using Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553367/less-unrecognized-input-error-when-using-bootstrap)